# java swing redrawing buttons

Tags: java, swing

I am pasting the following code here. I am puzzled at: why there are no JButtons added into the JPanel, even though the event was correctly listened and responded.

Thank you for your help.

```
import java.awt.Component;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class PanelControlButtons extends JFrame {
    private JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);

    public PanelControlButtons() {
        setSize(400, 300);
        getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        jPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        jPanel.add(jPanel1);
        jPanel.add(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.add(new JButton("abc"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            jPanel2.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i)));
        }
        jPanel1.add(jtf);
        jPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        jtf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    int key = e.getKeyCode();
                    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        System.out.println("ENTER pressed");
                        int n = Integer.parseInt(jtf.getText());
                        System.out.println(n);
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                            jPanel2.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PanelControlButtons panelControlButtons = new PanelControlButtons();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anytime you add a new component on a Container, you should call revalidate and repaint:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              jPanel2.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(i)));
           }
           jPanel2.revalidate();
           jPanel2.repaint();
```

The first to tell the layout managers to do their thing, the second to have the java paint manager repaint the container to redraw the dirty bits.

**Edit**
The revalidate and repaint methods moved out of loop as per mKorbel's excellent recommendation.

Comment: thank you for helping out! when you said "Anytime you add a new component", you mean inside an event listener? Otherwise, the first addition to jPanel2 does not need these.

Comment: @Qiang: anytime you add a component after the GUI has been rendered. When you are first creating your GUI, you usually call `pack();` on the root container after adding all the initial components, and this will call all the nested layout managers and lay out your gui as desired. Later if you add or remove a component, you will need to call revalidate (if the Container derives from JComponent, such as a JPanel or validate if not). Always if you remove a component and often if you add one, you will also need to call `repaint()'` on the Container as well.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels just move revalidate(); & repaint(); out off the loop then call that on the end and once time +1

Comment: @Qiang: Please see mKorbel's suggestion and my subsequent edit.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call [repaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29)/[validate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) on your `JPanel` after the key is pressed